# BEA-error WLContext.close() in python script

Tags: python, weblogic, wlst

I'm new to Weblogic.

Recently I've created my first script to deploy a WL application. The script is very simple. The problem is that the script throws an exception I don't know to solve.

The script looks like:

```
wlHost=sys.argv[1]
wlPort=sys.argv[2]
username=sys.argv[3]
password=sys.argv[4]

connect(username, password, "t3://" + wlHost + ":" + wlPort)
edit()
startEdit()
progress= deploy('MyApp','/path/to/server/classes')
progress.printStatus()
save()
activate()
exit()
```

Exception:

```
<Dec 11, 2011 10:41:35 AM EST> <Warning> <JNDI> <BEA-050001> <WLContext.close() was called in a different thread than the one in which it was created.>
```

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly sure your problem is `exit()` You don't run a `disconnect` method prior to exiting so the system is terminating all threads. Because you still have an active thread with an active connection open it's raising the exception.

Comment: I made changes as you suggest . The problem is still here. More than that I have an annoying icon "Warning" opposite the my application name in "Deployments" section

Comment: I get the same BEA-050001 exception, and I'm calling disconnect() before exit() as well. Ben you mention this error is referring to an active thread/connection, how can you determine that?